# Returning null in the method

Tags: java

How should I catch null in this part of code? If I dont have smth in input parameters, it should return null. But I know that returning null in catch statement is a bad practise. But how about a method retruning null? Is it also a bad practise? Any advice is appreciated.

```
 private LocalDateTime transferToLocalDateTime(Timestamp anyTime) {
            LocalDateTime date = null;
            try {
                date = anyTimetime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                log.error("Null", e);
//return null; //should I return it here?

            }
            return date;
```

Comment: _"should I return it here?"_ no.

Comment: Why don't you check for `anyTime == null` right at the start and return `null` if this is true? You should never catch a NPE since this would be an unanticipated exception (you want to either deal with nulls explicitly or don't expect anything to be null). You might also try to use (and especially return) `Optional` here.

Comment: or, possibly better, thow a NPE using `Objects.requireNonNull` or similar right at the start. (or alternatively, an `IllegalArgumentException`)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `Optional`s here.

```
private Optional<LocalDateTime> transferToLocalDateTime(Timestamp anyTime) {
  LocalDateTime date = null;
  if (Objects.nonNull(anyTime)) {
    date = anyTimetime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
  }
  return Optional.ofNullable(date);
}
```

And then check the result in the caller-class with `Optional.isPresent()` and get the value with `Optional.get()`.

Comment: One could even use `return Optional.ofNullable(anyTime).map(...)` since `map()` only is invoked if the value is present.

Comment: You can write `if (Objects.nonNull(anyTime))` more clearly as `if (anyTime != null)`

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to return `null` when `anyTime` is `null` is simply to put this at the start of the method:

```
if (anyTime == null) {
    return null;
}
```

Is that a good idea, though? It depends. Some people think that `null` values should be avoided (with different degrees of urgency) and if you follow that line of thought, then yes, this is a bad idea.

*However* following the avoid-`null`-at-all cost principle is something that can be really trick to only do in *parts* of your program: it's *much* easier to follow through if you can be sure that your code will never *get `null` passed in as well*.

So in my opinion: if you don't generally avoid `null` throughout your code, then this code is fine.

If you generally avoid `null` in your code, then chances are you want this method to throw a `NullPointerException` when called with `null` anyway and therefore don't need any special code at all.

Comment: How can I check it in one line? Is it possible?

Comment: You could just write `if (anyTime == null) return null` in one line, but breaks many code style suggestions requiring code blocks for all `if` statements. Alternatively you can move such a check to an external method (either one you write yourself or something like [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T))).